# Using "Or" operator in Business Objects (and failing)

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

This might be/seem like a basic question. Company just moved us to BO and trying to figure out a formula that would be easy in any other language. Can't seem to get the syntax and can't find documentation online.

```
=If([Disposition]=2 **Or 5**;Count([Sessionid]))
```

Apparently the "Or 5" part of this formula is wrong, cannot figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to list each condition separately.  If you update it like below you should have it corrected.

```
=If([Disposition]=2 Or [Disposition]=5;Count([Sessionid]))
```